# How to get default selected value in DropDown list using Html.DropdownList

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

This is my code:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("groupID", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.groupID, "    -- Select --  ", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Instead of string (-- Select --), i want to pass the selected value from the controller. Then, that selected value will be the default value in the dropdown list, instead of string. If I already know which group i will choose, i dont want to scroll down and search for it. Hope i have explained my problem well enough.

I tried ViewBag but it does not work. Is there another solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Your need to bind your dropdownlist to a property. If your model contains property `groupID`, then you must give the `SelectList` a different name (say `ViewBag.GroupList`). Then if you set the value of `groupID` to a value that matches the value of one of your options, that option will be selected.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.groupID, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.GroupList, "-- Select --", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: Hmm...this is my controller

public ActionResult Create(string sirovina)
        {
            ViewBag.Sirovina = sirovina;
            ViewBag.GroupList = new SelectList(db.groups, "ID", "name");
            ViewBag.measurment_unitID = new SelectList(db.measurmentunits, "ID", "type");
     
       
            return View();
        }

What shoud i change ?

Comment: OMG, Use a model and stop stuffing everything into `ViewBag` (and return the view in you GET method so you get proper 2-way model binding). And you have not even shown anything relating to a property named `groupID` - what are you actually wanting to bind the selected group to?

Comment: Here is a simple [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bszsPb) showing how your should be doing this

Comment: Hmm, Crud stuff all to the ViewBag. Ok i hope i can explain you what i want, becouse im new in MVC.

Comment: Hmm, Crud stuff all to the ViewBag. Ok i hope i can explain you what i want, becouse im new in MVC.

I want to bind all group to the select list, and want to have selected value, then populate dropdown list with selected list, with chosen item, that is selected value. 

Instead of string "-- Select --" that is default in dropdown i want to put some value, some groupID. Ok :) ?

Comment: Have you even looked at the fiddle I linked to above? - It shows you exactly how do do this. You need a model with a property to bind to (`GroupID`). In the GET method you set the value of `GroupID`. If that value matches one of the values of the options your generating (in your case the `ID` property of `group`, then that option will be selected.

Comment: Go to the fiddle, and in the GET method, change `model.GroupID = 2;` to (say) `model.GroupID = 50;` and you will see that the selected option is now `"--Please select--"` because no `Group` exists that has a value of `50`, But if you set it to any value between 1 and 4, then the correct option will be set.